# Joomla 3.6.4 Administration Error: Unable to load renderer class

Tags: joomla

I've received an error message while working with an extension. The error is : *Unable to load renderer class*

I really don't know what to do, on my local machine everything works fine.

Thank you so much

Comment: Please add some context to your question. Post your code, give the **full** error log, and explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which extension are you having the problem with? Is the error appearing everywhere on your website or on just one or a few pages?